# JavaScript: Remove a script from the head section using the script name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the following script from the `<head></head>` section of my document using `document.head.removeChild('temp_values_1.js');` but it will not work.

The file still remains in the `<head></head>` section when I view the console.

What is the right way to be doing this?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/static/js/temp_values_1.js"></script>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Remove Script</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/static/js/temp_values_1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="removeScript">Remove Script</div>
</body>

<script>

  const b = document.getElementById("removeScript");
  b.addEventListener("click",removeScript);

  function removeScript() {
    document.head.removeChild('temp_values_1.js');
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The value passed to `removeChild` must be an *element*; it doesn't accept a string.

You could find your script element using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with a [substring matching attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings).

Removing the script element will probably be an entirely pointless exercise, however, since the code in it will have already executed.